# Django REST framework foreign key with generics.ListCreateAPIView

Tags: python, django, generics, foreign-keys, django-rest-framework

How it is possible to get foreign key assigned in url with Django REST Framework?

```
class CommentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CommentSerializer(comment, many=True)
        return super(CommentList, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

My goal is to use this URL (urls.py):

```
url(r'^event/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comments', views.CommentList.as_view())
```

Somehow I managed to get foreign key with this way

```
class CommentLikeList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        key = self.kwargs['pk']
        commentLikes = CommentLike.objects.filter(pk=key)
        serializer = CommentLikeSerializer(commentLikes, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self):
        pass
```

But I don't know how to get foreign key with such URL using 
''generics.ListCreateAPIView''

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/event/<eventnumber>/comments
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the pk. You can use `lookup_url_kwarg` attribute from `ListCreateAPIView` class.

```
class CommentLikeList(ListCreateAPIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        key = self.kwargs[self.lookup_url_kwarg]
        commentLikes = CommentLike.objects.filter(pk=key)
        serializer = CommentLikeSerializer(commentLikes, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

> lookup_url_kwarg - The URL keyword argument that should be used for
>   object lookup. The URL conf should include a keyword argument
>   corresponding to this value. If unset this defaults to using the same
>   value as lookup_field.

The default value for `lookup_field` attribute is `'pk'`. So, if you change your url keyword argumento from another different to pk, you should define `lookup_url_kwarg` then.

```
class CommentLikeList(ListCreateAPIView):
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'eventnumber'
```

You can inspect all DRF classes methods and attributes over here:
http://www.cdrf.co/